# Error while programming a custom system call in the Linux kernel version 6.2.1

Tags: c, struct, linux-kernel, operating-system, system-calls

While writing a custom system call, I encountered the following problem:

`error: 'struct thread_info' has no member named 'pcb'`

The problem occurs when the make command is executed to build the kernel. In my code, I access the kernel thread_info structure in order to obtain data about it and pass it to the user level.

Here is my custom system call:

```
#include <linux/syscalls.h>
#include <linux/pid.h> 
#include <linux/sched.h>
#include <linux/uaccess.h>
#include "custom_thread_info.h"

SYSCALL_DEFINE2(gimme_thread_info, int, pid, void*, data)
{
    struct task_struct *task;
    struct thread_info *info;

    task = pid_task(find_vpid(pid), PIDTYPE_PID);
    if (task == NULL) {
        printk("ERR: ESRCH");
        return -ESRCH; //  not found
    }

    info = task_thread_info(task);
    if (info == NULL) {
        printk("ERR: EINVAL");
        return -EINVAL; //  invalid arg
    }

    struct custom_thread_info *c_t_i = kmalloc(sizeof(struct custom_thread_info), GFP_KERNEL);
    if (c_t_i == NULL) {
        printk("ERR: ENOMEM");
        return -ENOMEM; // no memory
    }

    c_t_i->palcode_ksp = info->pcb->ksp;
    c_t_i->palcode_usp = info->pcb->usp;
    c_t_i->palcode_ptbr = info->pcb->ptbr;
    c_t_i->palcode_pcc = info->pcb->pcc;
    c_t_i->palcode_asn = info->pcb->asn;
    c_t_i->palcode_unique = info->pcb->unique;
    c_t_i->palcode_flags = info->pcb->flags;
    c_t_i->palcode_res1 = info->pcb->res1;
    c_t_i->palcode_res2 = info->pcb->res2;

    if (info->task != NULL) {
        c_t_i->task_state = info->task->__state;
        c_t_i->task_prio = info->task->prio;
    } else {
        printk("WAR: info->task is null");
        c_t_i->task_state = 0;
        c_t_i->task_prio = -1;
    }
    
    c_t_i->flags = info->flags;
    c_t_i->ieee_state = info->ieee_state;
    c_t_i->cpu = info->cpu;
    c_t_i->preempt_count = info->preempt_count;
    c_t_i->status = info->status;
    c_t_i->bpt_nsaved = info->bpt_nsaved;
    c_t_i->bpt_addr[0] = info->bpt_addr[0];
    c_t_i->bpt_addr[1] = info->bpt_addr[1];
    c_t_i->bpt_insn[0] = info->bpt_insn[0];
    c_t_i->bpt_insn[1] = info->bpt_insn[1];

    
    if (copy_to_user(data, c_t_i, sizeof(struct custom_thread_info)) != 0) {
        kfree(c_t_i);
        printk("ERR: EFAULT");
        return -EFAULT; //  invalid address
    }

    kfree(c_t_i);
    printk("INF: OK");
    return 0;
}
```

As you can understand, the problem occurs when you call:

`info->pcb`

I tried to chat with chatGPT but no luck. My guess is that I didn't include some extra header file. Be that as it may, the thread_info structure from the Linux kernel [does contain a pcb field](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.1/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/thread_info.h#L16). Also among my assumptions is ignorance of the structure of some protected kernel structures...

Comment: [The reference](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.2.1/source/arch/alpha/include/asm/thread_info.h#L16) you show points to the structure definition on **alpha** platform. But it is unlikely that you program for that platform. If you are programming for x86, then its `thread_info` structure doesn't contain `pcb` field: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/arch/x86/include/asm/thread_info.h#L56

Comment: @Tsyvarev thank you very much! Your answer helped me a lot... I will be more careful in the future!